# Plotting a recursive piecewise function efficiently

Tags: recursion

Consider a recursive piecewise function K[t]:

```
   K[t_] := If[t <= 1, g[0, 0, t],
       If[t <= 2, g[K[1], 1, t],
        If[t <= 3, g[K[2], 2, t],
         If[t <= 4, g[K[3], 3, t],
          If[t <= 5, g[K[4], 4, t],
           0]]]]];
```

here g[x,y,z] is another function.

It can also be defined in a better way:

```
Block[{t}, 
  K[t_] = Piecewise[
    Table[{If[i > 1, g[K[i - 1], i - 1, t], g[0, 0, t]], t <= i}, {i, 
      5}]]];
```

However when we set 5 to a larger number such as 15, plotting K[t] becomes very slow. What will be the most efficient way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, lets check the output of your function.
For `t = 3.1`, your function returns `g[g[g[g[0, 0, 1], 1, 2], 2, 3], 3, 3.1]`. It can be seen that every time you change the input even a little bit, say `t = 3.11`, the function calculates the whole thing again i.e., `g[g[g[g[0, 0, 1], 1, 2], 2, 3], 3, 3.11]`. You can make it faster by memoizing the part `g[g[g[0, 0, 1], 1, 2], 2, 3]` which constitutes to `f[3]`.

Following is the memoized version of your function:

```
f[t_] := If[t <= 1, g[0, 0, t], g[f[Ceiling[t - 1]] = f[Ceiling[t - 1]],
Ceiling[t - 1], t]]
```

Note the memoization part: `f[Ceiling[t - 1]] = f[Ceiling[t - 1]]`

Comment: @Serendipity doesn't this answer give you what you want?

Comment: Yes and it's very fast. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One feature you can use to solve this problem is Mathematica's native multiple-dispatch. Your function can be defined as a set of separate functions, and the Mathematica engine will do the hard work of figuring out which one you've called:

```
K[t_Integer /; t <= 1] := g[0, 0, t];
K[t_Integer /; 1 < t <= 5] := g[K[t-1], t-1, t];
K[t_Integer /; t > 5] := 0;
```

(Here I'm assuming that your function `K` should only take integers.)

Here is some documentation on the patterns used to define these functions:

- [Conditional Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)
- [Pattern Reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html)
- [The `t_Integer` Construction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)
- [Introduction to Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html)

You could alternatively use a `Which` statement, which is like `cond` in lisps, or like `if`-`else` statements in C:

```
K[t_Integer] := Which[
  t <= 1, g[0,0,t],
  1 < t <= 5, g[K[t-1], t-1, t],
  True, 0];
```

**Closing Note:**

The slowness you're experiencing is probably due to the recursion and not due to the `Piecewise` specifically. You can likely get around this by memoizing your recursive results:

```
K[t_Integer /; 1 < t <= 5] := K[t] = g[K[t-1], t-1, t];
```

When that function (e.g., `K[4]`) is called, it calculates the result once then memoizes it so that future calls will just return the pre-calculated result. See here for details: [Memoizing in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

Comment: Thanks. The K takes Real values... So it seems to be a bit more difficult.

Comment: You can replace the `_Integer` with `_Real` to accept real values (or with `_?NumericQ` to accept either.